# mingw unresolved external when linking caused by naming convention confusion

Tags: c++, linker, mingw, mingw32

I am vainly trying to compile kmymoney using the emerge windows tool

all seems to go well until linking kmymoney

I get a huge number of unresolved references.

It appears the problem is that the libraries I am linking against are built without the windows specific `"_imp__"` on the exports but when I am compiling kmymoney the linker is expecting the `"_imp__"` + mangled name

For example the linker is looking for `_imp___ZNK7KLocale28negativeMonetarySignPositionEv`
but the export is called `_ZNK7KLocale28negativeMonetarySignPositionEv`

I assume I have to pass another flag or remove a flag from gcc to tell it to look for the correct export. but I am not sure how to do this. and cannot find the required documentation. even if I did I am not sure where to put it in the cmake file.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I have discovered that the libraries in fact do have the `_imp__` prefix

it appears there is a missing underscore

when I grep for one of the missing functions I get the following

```
r:\lib>nm *.a | grep _ZNK7KLocale28negativeMonetarySignPositionEv
00000000 T __ZNK7KLocale28negativeMonetarySignPositionEv
00000000 I __imp___ZNK7KLocale28negativeMonetarySignPositionEv
```

Clearly the prefix is there. but it looks like its missing the first underscore

The prefix is `__imp__` whereas the linker is looking for `_imp__`

Any ideas how I can resolve this??

Comment: Are you compiling all of the parts of the program yourself? Are you certain that the same versions of the compiler / librarian / linker are used for all of the parts? Exported symbols for a single toolset are consistent, so there shouldn't be any flags to influence the name munging scheme.

Comment: Yes I am compiling all parts myself - but its a very large process to get any package working requires compiling of all the dependent libraries for qt and KDE.